# How to concatenate multiple columns into single column (with no prior knowledge on their number)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let say I have the following dataframe:

```
agentName|original_dt|parsed_dt|   user|text|
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+
|qwertyuiop|          0|        0|16102.0|   0|
```

I wish to create a new dataframe with one more column that has the concatenation of all the elements of the row:

```
agentName|original_dt|parsed_dt|   user|text| newCol
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+
|qwertyuiop|          0|        0|16102.0|   0| [qwertyuiop, 0,0, 16102, 0]
```

Note: This is a just an example. The number of columns and names of them is not known. It is dynamic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this works perfect for your case 
here is with an example

```
val spark =
    SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    Seq(
      ("qwertyuiop", 0, 0, 16102.0, 0)
    )
  ).toDF("agentName","original_dt","parsed_dt","user","text")


  val result = data.withColumn("newCol", split(concat_ws(";",  data.schema.fieldNames.map(c=> col(c)):_*), ";"))        
  result.show()

+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+------------------------------+
|agentName |original_dt|parsed_dt|user   |text|newCol                        |
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+------------------------------+
|qwertyuiop|0          |0        |16102.0|0   |[qwertyuiop, 0, 0, 16102.0, 0]|
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+------------------------------+
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: _"The number of columns and names of them is not known"_ ;-)

Comment: Now it accepts any number of column. I have updated the answer @JacekLaskowski

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** Use `struct` function with `Dataset.columns` operator.

Quoting the scaladoc of [struct](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@struct(colName:String,colNames:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function:

> **struct(colName: String, colNames: String*): Column** Creates a new struct column that composes multiple input columns.

There are two variants: string-based for column names or using `Column` expressions (that gives you more flexibility on the calculation you want to apply on the concatenated columns).

From [Dataset.columns](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@columns:Array[String]):

> **columns: Array[String]** Returns all column names as an array.

---

Your case would then look as follows:

```
scala> df.withColumn("newCol",
  struct(df.columns.head, df.columns.tail: _*)).
  show(false)
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+--------------------------+
|agentName |original_dt|parsed_dt|user   |text|newCol                    |
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+--------------------------+
|qwertyuiop|0          |0        |16102.0|0   |[qwertyuiop,0,0,16102.0,0]|
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can merge multiple dataframe columns into one using array.

```
df.select($"*",array($"col1",$"col2").as("newCol")) \\$"*" will capture all existing columns
```

Here is the one line solution for your case:

```
df.select($"*",array($"agentName",$"original_dt",$"parsed_dt",$"user", $"text").as("newCol"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `udf` function to concat all the `columns` into one. All you have to do is define a `udf` function and pass all the `columns` you want to concat to the `udf` function and call the `udf` function using `.withColumn` function of `dataframe`

Or

You can use `concat_ws(java.lang.String sep, Column... exprs)` function available for dataframe.

```
var df = Seq(("qwertyuiop",0,0,16102.0,0))
  .toDF("agentName","original_dt","parsed_dt","user","text")
df.withColumn("newCol", concat_ws(",",$"agentName",$"original_dt",$"parsed_dt",$"user",$"text"))
df.show(false)
```

Will give you output as

```
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+------------------------+
|agentName |original_dt|parsed_dt|user   |text|newCol                  |
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+------------------------+
|qwertyuiop|0          |0        |16102.0|0   |qwertyuiop,0,0,16102.0,0|
+----------+-----------+---------+-------+----+------------------------+
```

That will get you the result you want

Answer (score 0):

There may be syntax errors in my answer. This is useful if you are using java<8 and spark<2.

```
String columns=null
For ( String columnName : dataframe.columns())
{
Columns = columns == null ? columnName : columns+"," + columnName;
}

SqlContext.sql(" select *, concat_ws('|', " +columns+ ") as complete_record " +
"from data frame ").show();
```