# How to load the csv file into the Spark DataFrame with Array[Int]

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

Every row in my csv file is structured like this:

```
u001, 2013-11, 0, 1, 2, ... , 99
```

in which *u001* and *2013-11* are UID and date, the number from *0* to *99* are the data value.  I want to load this csv file into the Spark DataFrame in this structure:

```
+-------+-------------+-----------------+
|    uid|         date|       dataVector|
+-------+-------------+-----------------+
|   u001|      2013-11|  [0,1,...,98,99]|
|   u002|      2013-11| [1,2,...,99,100]|
+-------+-------------+-----------------+

root
 |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dataVecotr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

in which dataVector is *Array[Int]*, and the *dataVector* length is the same for all of the UID and date.
I have tried several ways to solve this, including

1. Using shema

   ```
   val attributes = Array("uid", "date", "dataVector)
   val schema = StructType(
   StructField(attributes(0), StringType, true) ::
   StructField(attributes(1), StringType, true) ::
   StructField(attributes(2), ArrayType(IntegerType), true) :: 
   Nil)
   ```

But this way didn't work well.  For the column of data is larger than 100 in my later dataset, I think it is also inconvenience to create the schema including the whole columns of dataVector manually.

2. Directly load the csv file without schema, and use the method in [concatenate multiple columns into single columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200115/how-to-concatenate-multiple-columns-into-single-column-with-no-prior-knowledge) to concatenate the column of the data together, but the schema structure is like

   ```
    root
     |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
     |-- date: string (nullable = true)
     |-- dataVector: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- _c3: string (containsNull = true)
     |    |-- _c4: string (containsNull = true)
     .
     .
     .
     |    |-- _c101: string (containsNull = true)
   ```

This is still different from what I need, and I didn't find way to convert this struct into what I need.
So my question is that how could I load the csv file into the structure what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load it without any additions

```
val df = spark.read.csv(path)
```

and select:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

// Combine data into array
val dataVector: Column = array(
  df.columns.drop(2).map(col): _*  // Skip first 2 columns
).cast("array<int>")  // Cast to the required type
val cols: Array[Column] = df.columns.take(2).map(col) :+ dataVector

df.select(cols: _*).toDF("uid", "date", "dataVector")
```